# Method to install Elastic Search to Azure Kubernetes Services

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, azure-aks

I tried to run Elastic Search on Docker from my Mac successfully. However, I don't know how to find AKS's VM/Linux system to install Elastic Search. There is no specific guideline from [this elastic document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/7.5/metricbeat-module-kubernetes.html).

---

Supplement for steps that I performed:

```
# CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP=$(az aks show --resource-group XXX --name YYY --query nodeResourceGroup -o tsv)
# SCALE_SET_NAME=$(az vmss list --resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP --query [0].name -o tsv)

# az vmss extension set  \
--resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP \
--vmss-name $SCALE_SET_NAME \
--name VMAccessForLinux \
--publisher Microsoft.OSTCExtensions \
--version 1.4 \
--protected-settings "{\"username\":\"azureuser\", \"ssh_key\":\"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}"

# az vmss update-instances --instance-ids '*' \
--resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP \
--name $SCALE_SET_NAME

# kubectl get nodes -o wide
# az vm list --resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP -o table
# az vm list-ip-addresses --resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP -o table
# kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 -it --rm aks-ssh --image=debian

// Inside aks-ssh
apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-client -y

// Open another terminal then copy SSH key
# kubectl cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa $(kubectl get pod -l run=aks-ssh -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}'):/id_rsa

// Inside aks-ssh again
#chmod 0600 id_rsa
// Connect to vmss/VM:
#ssh -i id_rsa azureuser@10.240.0.4

// -- in VMSS --
// Download Metricbeat(use deb)
# curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/metricbeat/metricbeat-7.5.0-amd64.deb
# sudo dpkg -i metricbeat-7.5.0-amd64.deb

// Modify metricbeat.yml:
# sudo nano /etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
// Add below in “Elastic Cloud” section
cloud.id: "<--id-->"
cloud.auth: "<--auth-->"

// Enable Kubernetes
# sudo metricbeat modules enable kubernetes

// Modify kubernetes.yml
# sudo nano /etc/metricbeat/modules.d/kubernetes.yml

// Start Metricbeat
# sudo metricbeat setup
# sudo service metricbeat start
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup Elastic on ubuntu or VM you can simply install deb package using dpkg or using apt-get install. you can configure ES service and start running it.

You can find more details over here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/install-elasticsearch.html

If you are looking for whole solution Elasticsearch, logstash and kibana you can follow : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elastic-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-18-04/

However if you are looking for solution to install on **Kubernetes** you can use helm chart.

https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch

Comment: Hi @Harsh, I have my own Kibana dashboard already but want to monitor Kubernetes's VM and pod's resource usage. I follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh to connect to VMSS / VM then install Metricbeat already. But there is no data to send to Kibana.

Comment: @DeiKeung Do you route the metrics from MetricBeat to Elasticsearch? Do you have any progress on this?